# HREF redirect breaking the Nginx Proxy

Tags: nginx, proxy, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have a URL running behind Nginx Proxy (nginx.example.com.br/Manager),

This URL has a HREF link that is redirecting to local.example.com.br/manager.list,

I do not want to be redirect to the original domain, instead, i want to load nginx.example.com.br/manager.list

Config:

`upstream Manager {
server 10.1.2.38:80;
}

location /Manager {

```
    proxy_pass http://Manager$request_uri;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_pass_header $host;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Protocol $scheme;
    proxy_max_temp_file_size 0;
    client_max_body_size 100m;
    client_body_buffer_size 128k;
    proxy_connect_timeout 120s;
    proxy_send_timeout 120s;
    proxy_read_timeout 120s;
    proxy_buffer_size 4k;
    proxy_buffers 4 32k;
    client_body_timeout 90;
    keepalive_timeout 90;
    send_timeout 90;

}`
```

Best Whises.

Already tried to created another location with the correct URL.